# c3js: How to add a vertical line to a vertical bar chart that is not one of the categories of the x-axis?

Tags: reactjs, c3.js

I have created a histogram of some data, and would like to show a vertical line where the mean of this data is located. I am able to place a line at any of the categories on the bar chart, for example:

[image]

The code for doing this is (react-c3js):

```
<C3Chart
  key={foo}
  data={{ unload: true,
      columns: data.columns,
      type: 'bar',
      color: (color, d) => someColor
  }}
  grid={{
    x: {
      lines: [
        { value: '1332', text: 'mean' },
        { value: d3.mean(dataForHistogram), text: 'median' },
      ]
    },
    y: {
      lines: [
        { value: 100, text: 'oiweryoqeiuw' },
      ]
    }
  }}
  axis={{
    x: {
      unload: true,
      show: features ? true : false,
      categories,
      type: "category",
      label: someLabel,
    }
  }} />
```

Note that `1332` is not the actual mean - the correct mean is `2092`. But this is not a category value, so the line does not display when I use the mean as the value for the line.

How can I place a line representing the mean on such a bar chart?

Comment: Do you need this bar chart in d3 from scratch? because in c3 currently this facility not available

Comment: @ChandrakantThakkar: I would prefer it in c3, rather than making the chart from scratch in d3. Thanks.

Comment: You could add an SVG line over the C3 chart if you could reliably know the position in px. Also I see C3 has a feature called 'Regions' for line graphs via which a vertical or horizontal line can be shown. Could you add a line plot to the chart and use a region?  Am a bit new to C3 so do not know if either would be of use.

Comment: I have an idea - can you post the data.columns as JSON please so that I can see the starting point ?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat: Thanks for having a look. I found a solution, and will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone gave me the following solution, and it works for me. The solution was to change the type of x-axis from `category` to `linear` and to specify the `x` data:

```
const categories = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const yValues = [10, 8, 6, 3, 7];
const xDataName = 'my-x-data';
const data = {
  columns: [
    [xDataName, ...categories],
    [yData1, ...yValues],
  ],
};

return (<C3Chart
  key={foo}
  data={{
      x: xDataName, 
      unload: true,
      columns: data.columns,
      type: 'bar',
      color: (color, d) => someColor
  }}
  grid={{
    lines: {
      front: true 
    },
    x: {
      lines: [
        { value: d3.mean(yValues), text: 'mean' },
      ]
    }
  }}
  axis={{
    x: {
      unload: true,
      show: features ? true : false,
      categories,
      type: "linear",
      label: someLabel,
    }
  }} />)
```